# Proving the continuity of a difference of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, continuity

Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x=a$, then $(f-g)$ is continuous at $x=a.$

I have $|f(x)-f(a)-g(x)+g(a)| = |(f(x)-g(x))-(f(a)-g(a))|$ so far.  I wanted to use the triangle inequality on this but I'm not so sure that I can do that. Just need a little guidance!

Comment: Since I see this is homework, I am curious: are there any other results you're allowed to use? For instance, are you allowed to use the fact that $f+g$ and $cf$ are continuous? The triangle inequality is a perfectly valid approach, but laziness is a virtue!

Comment: I did just finish proving that f+g is continuous, so I'm sure my prof will allow it.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you use it! Even better, write two different proofs; one using that result and the other using the triangle inequality.

Comment: You should also prove that $cf$ is continuous if $f$ is. Then $f-g=f+((-1)g)$ will automatically be cont.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on the right track. You can use the triangle inequality whenever you want (if the conditions are right) and in this case it is certainly a good idea. If you are going for an $\epsilon-\delta $ proof here, then keep in mind that the quantities you can control are $|f(x)-f(x)|$ and $|g(x)-g(a)|$, so you want to manipulate the expression a bit before you apply the triangle inequality to get these quantities.

If you can use other results, then a quicker proof is possible.

Comment: suppose I was allowed to say that f+g is continuous.

Comment: Then use it for $f$ and $-g$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous at $x=a$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon/2$ and $|g(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon/2$ for any $\epsilon$ and the correct choices of $\delta$ for $f$ and $g$ respectively. Then, you can use the triangle inequality on the first part of what you have $|(f(x)-g(x))-(f(a)-g(a))| = |(f(x)-f(a))-(g(a)-g(x))|$. Remember that $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(a)-f(x)|$.